# its saying 1 record added but data base table empt.any solution for that?

Tags: php

this is an redirect page for form.this form will allow user to choose there group and database will store data into tables of selected groups.
 include'connection.php';

```
   if (isset($_POST['member']))
    {
    if (intval($_POST['member']) === Staff)
    {

        $insert1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblstaff(ST_Fname,ST_Sname,ST_Gender) VALUES``
                            ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[surname]','$_POST[sex]')");
    }
    else if (intval($_POST['member']) === Tutor)
    {
        $insert2=mysql_query( "INSERT INTO tbltutor(Tutor_Fname,Tutor_Sname,Tutor_Gender) VALUES
                     ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[surname]','$_POST[sex]')");
    }
    else if (intval($_POST['member']) === Student)

    {
        $insert3= mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblstudent(STU_Fname,STU_Sname,STU_Gender) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[surname]','$_POST[sex]')");
    }
    else
    {
        if (!mysql_query() === false)
                   {
                           die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                     }
                     else
                               echo "1 record added";


    }
}
```

its saying 1 record added but its not adding any data into database.

Comment: What is `Staff`, `Tutor`, `Student`?

Comment: these are the groups if user select staff it will store data into staffs table.

Comment: <select name="member">
            <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
            <option value="Tutor">Tutor</option>
            <option value="Student">Student</option> 
            </select>

Comment: Then `intval` doesn't make any sense. Also, if they're strings, you should quote them.

Comment: Set [error_reporting](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to E_ALL and you'll start to see a load of errors that you should set about fixing first. I would also suggest [going back to basics](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php) to make sure you understand some of the language constructs you're using.

Comment: where do i change it?is it in php.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you test for success:

```
if (!mysql_query() === false) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else
    echo "1 record added";
```

And this is how [mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query) is documented:

> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns **TRUE on success or FALSE on error**.

For some reason, you are expecting reverse return values: TRUE on error, FALSE on success.

*P.S. Please indent your code properly!*

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
if (isset($_POST['member']))
    {
     $insert = false;
    if (intval($_POST['member']) === Staff)
    {

        $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblstaff(ST_Fname,ST_Sname,ST_Gender) VALUES``
                            ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[surname]','$_POST[sex]')");
    }
    else if (intval($_POST['member']) === Tutor)
    {
        $insert=mysql_query( "INSERT INTO tbltutor(Tutor_Fname,Tutor_Sname,Tutor_Gender) VALUES
                     ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[surname]','$_POST[sex]')");
    }
    else if (intval($_POST['member']) === Student)

    {
        $insert= mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblstudent(STU_Fname,STU_Sname,STU_Gender) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[surname]','$_POST[sex]')");
    }
        if (!$insert)
                   {
                           die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                     }
                     else
                               echo "1 record added";



}
```